# Java error javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: when trying to read from webpage

Tags: java

I am using java to read from a webpage using this code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {

    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
}
```

When I run the code with eclipse on my windows pc it works fine, but when I try to run it on my raspberry pi, I get this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:     sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid     certification path to requested target
```

I think it means java doesn’t trust the website, but I can’t find a solution anywhere.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the website uses https:// then does it have a valid publicly signed certificate or something that's self-signed? Is the root ca cert installed on your RPi? Is the server certificate trusted? Have you looked at Certbot to get a free (no charge) publicly valid certificate?

Comment: Sorry if this is a noob question, but how would I go about installing the root ca cert on my pi?

Comment: Your local Google must be broken. https://www.bounca.org/tutorials/install_root_certificate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by updating java As described here:https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=200232

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer just with a link; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed or you risk to get down votes.